# .htaccess - how make rules apply to both specific pages and directories

Tags: .htaccess

I got help from this site to get functioning code for .htaccess:

```
# force https for /login.php and /register.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login|register)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !(login|register)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But now I realize I also need to add a couple of directories to these rules. How can this be done?

Why doesn't the following work:

```
# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(securimage|ADM)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(login|register)\.php$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !(securimage|ADM)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !(login|register)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I've tried a few different variances, nothing's working. :(

Comment: Add a couple directories to which rules exactly?

Comment: The rules for the login.php and register.php pages. I need to also force ssl for two directories, and make sure they're excluded in the last rule too of course, or they'd be forced to http if only added to first rule...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting separate .htaccess files in the directories I wanted to secure, containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```